# Switch case of strings in objective c

Tags: objective-c, switch-statement, mime-types

I would like to ask you which is the most efficient way to do something like a `switch (…)` statement of NSStrings in Objective-C.

What I want to do is a function that I send a File Extension (doc, txt, ...) and I get its MIME Type.

I was thinking in some array of key->value but I am not sure if would be the best way to do this.

What do you suggest me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare a static dictionary mapping from file extensions to mime types and simply query it:

```
NSDictionary *mimeTypes = nil;
static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
    mimeType = @{
        @"txt" : @"text/plain",
        @"doc" : @"application/msword",
        ....
    };
});
NSString *mimeType = mimeTypes[@"txt"]; // result: @"text/plain"
```